# NSTextField insertText:@"" doesn't work & Xcode doesn't recognize Label

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

i start a cocoaApplication in xcode 4.3.1 for mac and have below problems

1.when i want to connect an outlet to NSLabel, xcode doesn't recognize Label means that when i type NSLabel or UILabel in code doesn't recognize it 
2.i want to insert text in textfield with [txt insertText:@""] but doesn't work

Comment: Is this question about a text field or a label?

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare your UILabel in your header file.
2. Hook up the label from within interface builder.
3. Call `[myLabel setText: @"It worked!"];`

Comment: when i want to declare UILabel or NSLabel xcode doesn't recognize it and occur error